# Magento 2 + re-submit payment data

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

I created a custom credit card payment method. I tried to implement an error message when there's an error during checkout due to invalid inputs in payment method's credit card form. Sample error:
[image]

My problem is when I tried to update the payment form with the correct value, checkout data being sent is still the old one and not the updated one. Any idea on how refresh the payment method data during place order?

Comment: do you have full page cache turned on? if so have your tried it with it disabled

Comment: Yes, page cache is disabled. I don't think it has something to do with cache. The major issue is, I have custom payment method where payment data will send to the gateway through an api, and if some value in cc information is  invalid, the api will return an error, hence, error message will show up in checkout page. However, when I tried to correct the input values, Magento still sending the old payment values and not the updated one. I hope I'm making self clear.